# Matrix multiplication neural network style

Tags: r, performance, matrix-multiplication

Think of a neural network. Layer 1 has `n1` nodes. The data for them is stored in the columns of a `data.frame` or a `matrix`. In this example, it has 5 nodes (4 regular ones plus a column of ones for the "bias"):

```
l1 = head(iris[,1:4], 7)
l1$one = 1
```

Layer 2 has `n2` nodes. For calculating each Layer 2 node, I have a vector of weights. The length of each vector is `n1`. For example, with `n2 = 2`, the weights are

```
wts = list()
wts[[1]] = 1:5
wts[[2]] = -3:1
```

I need to calculate the values of the nodes in Layer 2. In other words,

- for each node of Layer 2 (`i in 1:n2`)
- for each row of the Layer 1 data
- multiply each element in that row of `l1` by the corresponding element in `wts[[i]]` and add up the products

What is an easy way to do this? I am mostly looking for **efficiency or speed**. I hope there are already functions to do this.

Comment: Use matrices. and if you really want efficiency, use numpy multiplication or a machine learning library to do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a single matrix-matrix multiplication:

```
as.matrix(l1) %*% do.call(cbind, wts)
```

It would be much easier if you store everything as matrices. Don't use data frames or lists here.

Comment: So basically you have a 7 x 5 (or 5 x 7) matrix and a 2 x 5 (or 5 x 2) matrix. They have a common "edge" 5. Do a matrix-matrix multiplication to eliminate this common edge. You may get either a 7 x 2 or 2 x 7 matrix.